# Prevent Recharts Y-axis labels from wrapping

Tags: reactjs, recharts

Currently my recharts labels are wrapping, I want to have specify a width so that they only wrap once that width has been exceeded. Right now each word is one it's own line, this is not what I want the behavior to be.

[image]

```js
<BarChartWrapper>
    <BarChart
        layout="vertical"
        width={668}
        height={248}
        barCategoryGap={20}
        data={data}
        margin={{ top: 0, right: 50, bottom: 0, left: 50 }}
    >
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="5" horizontal={false} stroke="#E7E7E7" />
        <XAxis
          label="(%)"
          // can also pass in a react component label={<CustomizedLabel />}
          tickLine={false}
          tickMargin={10}
          type="number"
          domain={[0, 90]}
        />
        {/* domain is max gonna be the max agreement + 10*/}
        <YAxis
          tick={{fontSize: 10, color: Colors.gray2}}
          tickLine={false}
          tickMargin={20}
          dataKey="name"
          type="category"
        />
        <Tooltip />
        <Bar dataKey="uv" barSize={24} fill="#009BAB" radius={[0, 4, 4, 0]} />
      </BarChart>
        </BarChartWrapper>
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the `Recharts YAxis tick` doesn't have the `whiteSpace` property for customizing the `tick` property but you can change the `YAxis` width with the `width` property to enhance the text wrapping issue:

```
<YAxis
  tick={{fontSize: 10, color: Colors.gray2}}
  tickLine={false}
  tickMargin={20}
  dataKey="name"
  type="category"
  width={300}     // ----> here
/>
```

The default `width` value is `60`. more information on rechart [documentation](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/YAxis#width).